# C shell. Make script wait for Gnome-terminal to finish

Tags: shell-script, gnome-terminal, csh, sleep

I am working on a script that has to process a lot of data. All comes down to 3 commands.
I use:

```
#!/bin/csh

gnome-terminal -e "ssh $servername1 'command 1'" &
gnome-terminal -e "ssh $servername2 'command 2'"

command 3
```

I now have to wait for command 1 and 2 to finish, before starting command 3.
I have tried using 'wait' and 'pid', although i cannot get it to wait.
It looks like my scripts sees the command as done, when the gnome-terminal has opened.

Comment: Remove the first "&" and run a one liner "gnome-terminal -e "ssh $servername1 'command 1 & command 2 & command 3'"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that doesn't do any waiting. It also executes "command 3" remotely whereas it appears he wants that one to be local.

Comment: "gnome-terminal -e "ssh $servername1 'command 1 && command 2' && command 3'"